# Strange issue in Access database - cannot insert due to key violation while no key has been violated

Tags: ms-access

I have ran a number of insert into table Table1 of the following structure:

```
Table1
_________
ID - Number - Double - No dups, Primary key
Field1 - Number - Integer - Dups OK
```

My insert is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(ID, Field1)VALUES(10001392, 7)
```

and the error I get is that

```
"Microsoft Access can't append all records in the append query."
```

and

```
"it didn't add 1 record(s) to the table due to key violations"
```

The interesting part that ID 10001392 is not in the table so I am sure it is not attempting to insert duplicates. Also similar insert worked just fine:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(ID, Field1)VALUES(10001391, 5)
```

I am lost...

Comment: A key violation error can also happen when the table is included in a defined relationship with another table.  Does that apply here?

Comment: A `Double` column is IMHO a very bad choice for a Primary Key. Can you change this field to Long Integer?

Comment: HansUp, you were close! actually the issue was that the ID key needed to exist in another table. Please post an answer so I could accept it